# In Mercurial Is it "safe" to pull when a mq patch is applied?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-queue

The [go programming language has a page on code reviews](http://golang.org/doc/codereview_with_mq.html) using mq and it states:  "Since pulling, pushing, updating and committing while mq patches are applied can damage your repository".

I understand why pushing or updating could be an issue, but is pulling an issue?

If you have mq patches applied and you pull will your repository be damaged?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can certainly be an issue if you accidentally merge with the upstream changesets while you have MQ patches applied in your repository.  Here's a scenario I just tried out which seems to exhibit problems:

- suppose in your clone, you push all of your patches with `hg qpush -a`
- then you pull changesets from upstream with `hg pull` (but don't `hg update`).  this creates a new branch (`hg heads` shows the branch you're on as `qtip` and the new branch you just pulled as `tip`)
- as you're hacking away, you decide to switch over to the new branch, and run `hg update -C tip`, but do so *without* popping your patches.
- as you hack away some more, you decide to merge the branches with `hg merge`.  Oops!  You just merged in an MQ patch that was never `qfinished`.

Since  MQ works by creating and destroying history, the patch changesets look like normal parts of the history.  However, since you "leap-frogged" over the applied patches and merged them with a *non*-patch changeset, you can no longer pop the patches off.  In fact, running `hg qpop` will abort with a message saying:

```
abort: popping would remove a revision not managed by this patch queue
```

I generally just try to be careful and conscious about pulling or pushing when I'm working with a patch queue, but the hooks suggested by the go page provide a nice safeguard.

Note that you can always rebase your patches on top of upstream changesets as well.  See [this page](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqMerge) for a description of how to do that.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something in the explanation, but the pull doesn't seem to be the issue in the scenario you describe.  I understand the pull allows you to have a new branch, but you could have started this way.  I guess my question is looking for a more boolean answer and not a scenario ;-)  I'll try to clarify in my question.

Comment: I think you're correct, pull is not necessarily the issue.  In fact, in the scenario I described if you pull and then qpop before switching branches, you should have no problems at all.  Even if you pull and then try to merge without switching to the new branch, MQ seems also to be smart enough to prevent you from doing that (at least on hg 1.6 which is where I tested).

My guess is the Go team recommends the hook as a safeguard against situations like I described, which can corrupt your patch queue and ultimately the repo history.

Comment: This will be fixed in Mercurial 1.8.1 -- I just pushed a patch for it: http://hg.intevation.org/mercurial/crew/rev/9510ddf87c43

Comment: Please send a mail to mercurial@selenic.com if you find other bugs!

Answer (score 6):

> If you have mq patches applied and you pull will your repository be damaged?

The answer is **no**. When you pull, you add more changesets to your local history. The applied MQ patches also live as changesets in the changeset graph, but that's not dangerous and you will not lose any data.

What *may* happen is that you have applied some patches:

```
.... a --- b --- p1 --- p2 --- p3
```

You then send the patches to the upstream mailinglist for inclusion. Someone reviews the patches, commits them, and pushes the changesets to the main repository. Other changesets are pushed afterwards and next time you pull you end up with:

```
.... a --- b --- p1 --- p2 --- p3 --- c --- d
```

Changesets `p1` to `p3` are still MQ patches in your repository, but they now have *non-MQ* children! Trying to pop them results in (with Mercurial 2.1.1):

```
$ hg qpop
abort: popping would remove a revision not managed by this patch queue
```

This is a bit of a dead-lock. It's annoying but not dangerous. To resolve it you must make MQ understand that `p1` to `p3` are no longer managed by MQ. You do this by removing the lines for these changesets from `.hg/patches/status`. MQ should probably eventually remove these lines by itself when this happens — but it happens pretty rarely so nobody has written that patch yet.